# multiple Increment/Decrement buttons with useState fails

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

I use decrement/increment buttons on two/multiple input fields but as soon as I trigger a second input field button set, I get the following error-messages/warnings:

Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type undefined to be uncontrolled.

and the second field value goes from number to NaN.

```
const [formField, setFormField] = useState({ drivingTime: 5, shorePower: 15 });

const handleOnChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormField({ [name]: parseInt(value, 10) });
};

const IncrementItem = (name) => {
    setFormField(prev => ({ [name]: parseInt(prev[name], 10) + 1 }));
}

const DecreaseItem = (name) => {
    setFormField(prev => ({ [name]: parseInt(prev[name], 10) - 1 }));
}
```

and the inputs as follows:

```
 <input
  name="drivingTime"
  value={formField.drivingTime}
  onChange={handleOnChange}
  ref={register({ required: true })}
/>

<button className="btnIncrease" onClick={() => IncrementItem('drivingTime')}>+</button>
<button className="btnDecrease" disabled={formField.drivingTime < 1} onClick={() => DecreaseItem('drivingTime')}>-</button>
```

and

```
  <input
   name="shorePower"
   value={formField.shorePower}
   onChange={handleOnChange}
   ref={register({ required: true })}
  />

  <button className="btnIncrease" onClick={() => IncrementItem('shorePower')}>+</button>
  <button className="btnDecrease" disabled={formField.shorePower< 1} onClick={() => DecreaseItem('shorePower')}>-</button>
```

What exactly do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const IncrementItem = (name) => {
    setFormField(prev => ({ ...formField, [name]: parseInt(prev[name], 10) + 1 }));
}

const DecreaseItem = (name) => {
    setFormField(prev => ({ ... formField, [name]: parseInt(prev[name], 10) - 1 }));
}
```

i think you have overwritten your state, change IncrementItem and DecreaseItem to this
.Sr for my bad english

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. This was it! (and EN is very good!) Thank you!

Comment: thank you :D
this error can be cause by getting undefined input 's value . next time take a look at that, or smt like `value={formField?.drivingTime || ''}` @Marek123